# What size of chucks should I dd write Raspbian OS to my SD card for my Raspberry Pi

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi

I know i can order the preloaded NOOBs SD card which will let me easily install a selection of linux distro's for my raspberry pi. However, i'm going to be testing out different distros so I would like to know what it means and what i'm doing when i do a dd write and specify the command bs=size_to_write

I've been told that when i do a dd write and specifying bs=512  it will write my image file in 512K blocks to the SD card. I'm not quite understanding this completely. I've been told to write in chunks of 1k to 4k instead. I would like some clarification on what i'm actually doing here and what a reasonably default size would be.

Answer (score 1):

The chunks control how much is read from the source to memory, before the target is written with the content in the memory. Larger chunks are usually faster, but consume more memory (and processor, sometimes). Some cards work better with some special chunk sizes, but generally, you don't have to care about that.

Good luck with your raspberry pi!